# How to correctly set default in time_zone_select based on Time.zone (abbreviated vs extended names) in Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently we've been seeing that our `time_zone_select` defaults are incorrect. I think this might have been since our upgrade to Rails 5. In short, we have the following bit of code:

```
f.time_zone_select :timezone, nil, { default: Time.zone.name }
```

The problem here is that `time_zone_select` compiles an options list where the values are "abbreviated" names, by which I mean (e.g.) `Amsterdam` instead of `Europe/Amsterdam`.

This now goes wrong when using `Time.zone.name` to set the default, since that returns `Europe/Amsterdam`. As a result, the default is not selected.

It this a bug or am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 1):

Diving into this shows that in version 5.1.6.2 of ActiveSupport::TimeZone the `time_zone_select` works as documented, allowing us to simply select a valid default time zone with `Time.zone.name`. Albeit that if the default is (e.g.) "Europe/Amsterdam", the select options contain both "Amsterdam" as well as "Europe/Amsterdam".

So I guess the changes made to ActiveSupport::TimeZone in Rails 5.2.0 have insufficiently taken into account the impact these have on `time_zone_select`. For now, instead of using a the extended time zone name (like "Europe/Amsterdam") to select a `time_zone_select` default, I'm explicitly normalizing that to the abbreviated form as a workaround, like so:

```
# As of Rails 5.2.0 the time_zone_select helper does not accept time zones in format "Europe/Amsterdam"
# anymore. Instead, we should cast this to a selectable value, being "Amsterdam" in this example.
def selectable_time_zone_name(zone_name)
  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.find{|tz| tz =~ zone_name }&.name
end
```

which we can then use like so (this includes migrating any extended name value that the timezone attribute might already have):

```
<% form.object.timezone = selectable_time_zone_name(selectable_time_zone_name(form.object.timezone) || Time.zone.name) %>
<%= form.time_zone_select :timezone %>
```